# VSTS Build - The replacement token 'version' has no value

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

I have setup my very first Build definition in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online).

It builds, all tests pass and then it finally pops this error:

> Attempting to build package from 'EvoqPortaCoreDistrib.nuspec'.
>   The replacement token 'version' has no value.
>   Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

This is after clearing some other problems it found with my nuspec file. Though oddly enough, I've used this nuspec to push packages manually from my desktop PC to a feed hosted somewhere else. The difference being that I've updated to NuGet 3.3 today.

So its saying that there's no assembly version? Which is frankly, impossible.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your nuspec file? Does it have a <version> element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hang on. Apparently, when you supply your own `.nuspec` file, the VSO build goes all dumb.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/package/nuget-packager

> The packager does not compile the .csproj files for packaging. Each
>   project is packaged only if it has a .nuspec file checked in. The
>   packager does not replace tokens in the .nuspec file (except the
>    element, see Use build number to version package, below).
>   You must supply values for elements such as  and .
>   The most common way to do this is to hardcode the values in the
>   .nuspec file.

So I'll take out my `.nuspec` file.

Comment: Old post, but I'm not sure this is quite right [any more]:
"You do not have to check in a .nuspec file. If you do check one in, the packager honors its settings and replaces tokens such as $id$ and $description$."

Comment: But still not $version$

Comment: I'm using NuGet "task version 2.*" / exe version 4.4.1 in Azure DevOps. It did update my nuspec's $version$ token correctly. But, I pretty much had to take out all the other things like $author$ and $description$ and hard code them due to errors described by the OP